# markdown spoiler doesn't work in stackoverflow

Tags: testing, markdown

From [**Spoilers**](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers)

> To hide a certain piece of text and have it only be visible when a
>   user moves the mouse over it, use the blockquote syntax with an
>   additional exclamation point:

doesn't looks working

> At the end of episode five, it turns out that  >! he's actually his father.

Comment: this should be on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Yes. I have requested to move. it need 4 more close vote to move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says `blockquote syntax`, so the `>!` needs to be on a newline, then it works:

```
At the end of episode five, it turns out that:
>! he's actually his father.
```

renders as:

> At the end of episode five, it turns out that:
>
> > he's actually his father.

Comment: Thanks. additionally upper line is not necessarily in block quote

Comment: I just tried this at https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88565/who-is-eric-cartmans-father/88567#88567 and it did not work.